# A Zeppelin Spark statement fails on a ClassCastException on an $iw class coming from 2 differents classloaders (?). it doesn't happen with spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, classloader, apache-zeppelin

if I am interpreting this exception well, when I'm using *Zeppelin* to execute a *Spark* statement written in *Scala*, it fails with a `ClassCastException` involving an `$iw` class:

- in loader `org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader`
- against one coming from loader: `scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$TranslatingClassLoader`

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3) (192.168.1.153 executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException: class $iw cannot be cast to class $iw ($iw is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader @69bd1241; $iw is in unnamed module of loader scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$TranslatingClassLoader @5a68e587)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.deserializetoobject_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
```

[image]

These two cells do execute correctly if I'm using `spark-shell` from a command line:

```scala
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import spark.implicits._
case class Flight(DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: String,
                  ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: String,
                  count: BigInt)
val flightsDF = spark.read
  .parquet("/home/lebihan/dev/apprentissageDev/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide/data/flight-data/parquet/2010-summary.parquet/")
val flights = flightsDF.as[Flight]

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import spark.implicits._
defined class Flight
flightsDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: string, ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: string ... 1 more field]
flights: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Flight] = [DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: string, ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: string ... 1 more field]

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

flights
  .filter(flight_row => flight_row.ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME != "Canada")
  .map(flight_row => flight_row)
  .take(5)

flights
  .take(5)
  .filter(flight_row => flight_row.ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME != "Canada")
  .map(fr => Flight(fr.DEST_COUNTRY_NAME, fr.ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME, fr.count + 5))

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

res7: Array[Flight] = Array(Flight(United States,Romania,6), Flight(United States,Ireland,269), Flight(United States,India,74), Flight(Egypt,United States,29), Flight(Equatorial Guinea,United States,6))
```

So I believe I'm stumbling upon some kind of configuration mess, in *Zeppelin*.

But what should I check to resolve it?

My spark interpreter has for `SPARK_HOME`, `/opt/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7`,
but I don't see anything about a *Scala* version property to control anywhere, if it's what I shall check...

What am I in front of?